# How to split this Xpath?

Tags: java, string

```
givenString =  "/DATA[1]/ASSET[1]/DET[5]/INT[1]/VAL[1]/text()[1]"
findString = "DET"
```

Output I am expecting is "/DATA[1]/ASSET[1]/DET[5]/"

I have to find the String "DET" and other characters until I reach first "/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `DET` would only appear once, you could use a regex replacement here:

```java
String givenString = "/DATA[1]/ASSET[1]/DET[5]/INT[1]/VAL[1]/text()[1]";
String findString = "DET";
String output = givenString.replaceAll("(.*/" + findString + "[^/]*/).*", "$1");
System.out.println(output);
```

This prints:

```
/DATA[1]/ASSET[1]/DET[5]/
```

The idea here is to match the entire string on the following regex pattern:

```regex
^(.*/DET[^/]*/).*$
```

Then, we replace with just the first capture group `$1`, which should contain the path you want.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach without using regex would be this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     String   givenString =  "/DATA[1]/ASSET[1]/DET[5]/INT[1]/VAL[1]/text()[1]" ;
        String  findString = "DET";

        List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(givenString.split("/"));

        StringBuilder expectedOutput = new StringBuilder();
        Iterator itr = stringList.iterator();

       while (itr.hasNext()){
           String temp = (String) itr.next();
           expectedOutput.append(temp+"/");
           if(temp.startsWith("DET"))
               break;
       }

        System.out.println(expectedOutput.toString());

    }


    //Output
    /DATA[1]/ASSET[1]/DET[5]/
```